# Combine display: inline and text-indent

Tags: html, css

I want to combine `display: inline` and `text-indent`. I read that it is not possible. Therefore, I a workaround.

How it looks now:

[image]

How it should look like:

[image]

I tried to use `<article>`. But this only works with one p tag.

Does anyone know how I can get this?

**FIDDLE**: https://jsfiddle.net/h22ede56/11/

```css
article {
  text-indent: -20px;
  padding-left: 20px
}
.seitenumbruch{
  display: inline
}
p._10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb {
  font-size: 0.783em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.223;
  margin-left: 9px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  orphans: 1;
  page-break-after: auto;
  page-break-before: auto;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  widows: 1;
}
p._10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb_tab {
  font-size: 0.783em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.223;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  orphans: 1;
  page-break-after: auto;
  page-break-before: auto;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  widows: 1;
}
p._10_Lesetext_02_Txt {
  font-size: 0.783em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.223;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  orphans: 1;
  page-break-after: auto;
  page-break-before: auto;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  widows: 2;
}
span.semibold-semicondensed {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro Semibold", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
}
span._idGenCharOverride-1 {
  font-size: 0.958em;
}
```

```html
 <div id="page169" title="170" class="seitenumbruch">
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb"><span class="semibold-semicondensed _idGenCharOverride-1">Name.</span> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
  </div>  
  <div id="page170" title="170" class="seitenumbruch">
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb seitenumbruch"><span class="semibold-semicondensed _idGenCharOverride-1">Name.</span> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="page171" title="171" class="seitenumbruch">
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt seitenumbruch">together Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb"><span class="semibold-semicondensed _idGenCharOverride-1">Name.</span> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb"><span class="semibold-semicondensed _idGenCharOverride-1">Name.</span> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: _“I tried to use <article>”_ – you tried to style `article` in your CSS in the fiddle, but you have no `article` element in the HTML.

Comment: And what is the purpose of using `inline` here in the first place?

Comment: Why not just use padding on the p and minus margin on the bold element: https://jsfiddle.net/h22ede56/4/

Comment: @CBroe: I deleted it. Because it didn't work. I put it around all the html. The purpose is that the text 'be together' should be together. Without `display: inline`, 'together' would be in the next line.

Comment: @Pete: Now, the text in the second part is divided.

Comment: @GCyrillus: Now, the text in the second part is divided

Comment: @chocolatecake why would you put together text in a new p tag separated by a div - if it's a new paragraph then it should be displayed as such otherwise it isn't really semantically correct

Comment: @Pete: Do you see the `id="page171"`? I need this to know where the next page begins. The app is an ebook reader.

Comment: You may wish to look into [shorthand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) to make your CSS more concise. It won't help your current issue, but it will make it easier to read the CSS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can add a container div (which is needed for the left padding), then through a mixture of inline and before psuedo elements, you can achieve what you want:

```css
.container {
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.seitenumbruch,
p {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p._10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
}

.semibold-semicondensed {
  margin-left: -1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="page169" title="170" class="seitenumbruch">
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb"><strong class="semibold-semicondensed _idGenCharOverride-1">Name.</strong>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="page170" title="170" class="seitenumbruch">
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb seitenumbruch"><strong class="semibold-semicondensed _idGenCharOverride-1">Name.</strong> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="page171" title="171" class="seitenumbruch">
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt seitenumbruch">together Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb"><strong class="semibold-semicondensed _idGenCharOverride-1">Name.</strong> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    <p class="_10_Lesetext_02_Txt_lb"><strong class="semibold-semicondensed _idGenCharOverride-1">Name.</strong> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h22ede56/10/)